# Java class compiles but cannot be loaded

Tags: java, import

I have compiled a class and the file shows up but I can not run it with java or use it from other classes, where either java or javac act as if it isn't there.

It compiles...

```
john@fekete:~/devel/java/mysqlexample$ javac first/mysql/MySQLAccess.java 
Note: first/mysql/MySQLAccess.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

It doesn't seem to exist to java...

```
john@fekete:~/devel/java/mysqlexample$ java first/mysql/MySQLAccess.class
Error: Could not find or load main class first.mysql.MySQLAccess.class
john@fekete:~/devel/java/mysqlexample$ java first/mysql/MySQLAccess
Error: Could not find or load main class first.mysql.MySQLAccess
```

I can't use it from other classes.

```
first/mysql/test/Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import first.mysql.MySQLAccess;
                   ^
  symbol:   class MySQLAccess
  location: package first.mysql
```

The files are structured as such and I compile from the root of that structure.

```
john@fekete:~/devel/java/mysqlexample$ ls -l first/mysql/
total 12
-rwxr-xr-x 1 john john 3625 May  2 07:59 MySQLAccess.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 3052 May  2 07:59 MySQLAccess.java
drwxr-xr-x 2 john john 4096 May  2 08:02 test
john@fekete:~/devel/java/mysqlexample$ ls -l first/mysql/test/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 205 May  2 08:02 Main.java
```

Importing first.mysql.* does not work.

Perhaps I need to change my classpath.

```
john@fekete:~/devel/java/mysqlexample$ echo $CLASSPATH 
/usr/local/mysql-connector-java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `java` command invokes the JVM, which doesn't run source code.  So

```
java first/mysql/MySQLAccess.java
```

won't work as it is written.  Instead you need to call the *resource* name, which would be

```
java first.mysql.MySQLAccess
```

except that the above command line is *likely* to not work because you *probably* haven't configured your JVM to search the current directory for class hierarchy trees.  You probably want something like

```
java -classpath . first.mysql.MySQLAccess
```

to load in the class at `first/mysql/MySQLAccess.class`; but, that's not the *whole* story.  The CLASSPATH environmental variable also comes into play, which is how it will load the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar`.  However, if you run into problems, I suggest that you make its inclusion explicit, like so

```
java -classpath .:/usr/local/mysql-connector-java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar first.mysql.MySQLAccess
```

Comment: Ah I had to have . in my classpath. Thanks heaps this was really bugging me, but at least I learned something from the experience.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.java` when trying to run java classes.

Also, make sure your class has a main method, and that it is in the package `first.mysql`, that can be a reason why other classes can't see it.

Comment: I added a main method, still nothing can see it.